# Small Popover Alert on IOS IPhone Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have been struggeling to find a solution for a small popover alert in swift. My goal is to add a small sheet under a certain object (for example my messageView), which has multiple options like for example delete message or share message, like you can see in that image:
[Image with a small popover sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CUzT.jpg)

I already tried to add a popover View Controller to my view but I didn't manage to get a type of alert like in that example to work.

Comment: Look up either `UIContextMenu` or `UIMenu`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It's nothing but a custom-shaped window appearing as a `UIView` object.